# Is there a standard way to list entry tags in an Atom feed?

Tags: xml, atom-feed

Say I have a series of tags (such as "travel", "Paris", "cheese") attached to a post or entry. Is there a standard way of listing those tags in an Atom feed? Even if there isn't, is there a de facto standard that is used by most feed readers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Atom defines [a 'category' element](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4287#section-4.2.2) for general classification of posts. [Theresa O’Connor](https://tess.oconnor.cx/)'s [Representing Tags in Atom](https://tess.oconnor.cx/2007/02/representing-tags-in-atom) is a good summary of the ways this can be used for tags, with advice about benefits.